# how to copy groovy properties to java bean properties

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I want to copy a groovy object properties to another java object,and I know groovy to groovy is like  this

```
def copyProperties(source, target) {
    source.properties.each { key, value ->
        if (target.hasProperty(key) && !(key in ['class', 'metaClass']))
            target[key] = value
    }
}
```

java to java I can useed apache BeanUtils, but how to copy groovy object properties to java object properties?
ps:
groovy object

```
class UserInfo {
    Integer age
    String userName
    String password
}
```

java object

```
 public class UserInfo {
    private int age;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you face any problem using `copyProperties()` for the same?

Answer (score 1):

```
def copyProperties(source, Object target) {
    source.properties.each { key, value ->
        Class<? extends Object> toClass = target.getClass();

        try {
            BeanInfo toBean = Introspector.getBeanInfo(toClass);

            PropertyDescriptor[] toPd = toBean.getPropertyDescriptors();

            for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : toPd) {
                propertyDescriptor.getDisplayName();

                if (key.equals(
                        propertyDescriptor.getDisplayName())
                        && !(key in ['class', 'metaClass'])) {
                    if(propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod() != null)
                        propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod().invoke(target, value);
                }

            }
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I got it by myself~

Comment: You're not trying hard enough - you could make that way more verbose.